# How could one block detect that its inside another block?

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
def block
  puts "from block"
  yield
end

block do
  puts "from command line"
  block do

  end
end
```

Here is the output:

```
from block
from command line
from block
```

I wonder how the second block could detect that its inside another block (of the same method).

So that the output will be this instead:

```
from block 1
from command line
from block 2
```

Is this possible? Because I want the nested block to be aware of this and run some additional code.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a better way to structure the code, such that this isn't necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep track of the block level with an instance variable, increment it whenever you enter a block, and decrement it whenever you leave a block:

```
def block
  @block_level ||= 0
  @block_level += 1

  puts "from block #@block_level"

  yield

  @block_level -= 1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is mostly just for fun, I don't suggest you use it.

Ruby lets you inspect the call stack in the form of a backtrace, but only when an exception is raised. So let's raise an exception and then stick out our arm and catch it before it goes to anyone else, and then: the backtrace is all ours!!

Then all you need to do is search the backtrace (an array) for any method calls to our method named "block", and count them.

```
class InspectBacktrace < Exception
end

def block
  raise InspectBacktrace
rescue InspectBacktrace => e
  level = e.backtrace.count { |x| x =~ /in `block'/ }
  puts "from block #{level}"
  yield
end

block do
  puts "from command line"
  block do
    puts "from command line"
    block do
      puts "from command line"
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
from block 1
from command line
from block 2
from command line
from block 3
from command line
```

**Edit:** I've since come across the `Kernel#caller` method which just gives you the current execution stack with no hassles. So the following code *might* be acceptable, as long as you don't have two methods named "block" in the same file that call each other:

```
def block
  level = caller.count { |x| x =~ /^#{ Regexp.escape(__FILE__) }:\d+:in `block'$/ } + 1
  puts "from block #{level}"
  yield
end
```

Comment: i like that you are creative =)

Answer (score 1):

What yjerem says, just use `ensure` to avoid troubles with exceptions, and it sounds like a global variable, not instance variable.

```
def block
  begin
    $block_level ||= 0
    $block_level += 1
    puts "from block #{$block_level}"
    yield
  ensure
    $block_level -= 1
  end
end
```